# Use map inside map?

Tags: list, tidyverse

I have two lists: One with some tidy data and another with models made with tidymodels package

```
data_list <- list(train,test)
model_fits <- list(tree,forest,xgb)
```

I want to make a new list with a confusion matrix for train and test for every model.

The function that calculates confusion matrix:

```
ConfMat <- 
  function(df,data){
    df <- 
    predict(df,new_data = data, type = "class") %>% 
    mutate(truth = data$NetInc) %>% 
    conf_mat(truth,.pred_class)}
```

I have tried to do this (x,y is arbitrary).:

```
map(data_list,map(model_fits,ConfMat(x,y)))
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to actually set "x" and "y" right.

PS: double for loop works. I'm asking specifically for map solution or equivalent.

Appreciate all help i can get! cheers

Answer (score 1):

Use an anonymous function -

```
library(purrr)
result <- map(data_list,function(x) map(model_fits,function(y) ConfMat(x,y)))

result
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah: can you please take a look at this question if you have tlme? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70231544/re-writing-fuzzy-join-functions-from-r-to-sql thank you!